# Registro de asiento

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola a todos tengo esta siguiente consulta ,tengo esta base en la cual registro ,la fecha, nombre,tipo, y asiento. En tipo registro si es entrada o salida, y en asiento un numero ejemplo:5
lo que necesito hacer es que por Fecha y nombre, Tipo no se puede duplicar el asiento por otra persona.

resumiento: quiero registrar un asiento y que otra persona no pueda ocuparlo sea entrada y salida.y que el otro dia pueda hacer lo mismo.

```
SELECT
Fecha,
Nombre,
Tipo,
Asiento
FROM registro
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Podrías añadir lo que has intentado y un ejemplo de lo que deseas lograr? Saludos

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas deben incluir la estructura de las tablas involucradas para ver si tienen indices o relaciones, además de datos de prueba y el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo aplicando un índice o restricción `UNIQUE` en la tabla.

Antes de mostrar un código de ejemplo, vamos a explicar en qué consisten estos índices.

En MySQL existen dos tipos de índices para expresar la unicidad de registros en las tablas: la llave primaria (`PRIMARY KEY`) y `UNIQUE`.

Para aplicar el valor de unicidad de una o más columnas, a menudo se utiliza la restricción `PRIMARY KEY`. Sin embargo, cada tabla solo puede tener una llave primaria. Por lo tanto, si deseas tener más de una columna o un conjunto de columnas con valores únicos, no puedes usar la restricción de llave primaria.

Para estos casos puedes usar `UNIQUE`, que te permite imponer la unicidad de los valores en una o más columnas. A diferencia del índice `PRIMARY KEY`, puedes tener más de un índice `UNIQUE` por tabla.

Para crear un índice `UNIQUE`, puedes usar la instrucción `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name(index_column_1,index_column_2,...);
```

Otra forma de imponer la unicidad del valor en una o más columnas es usar la restricción `UNIQUE`. Cuando creas una restricción `UNIQUE`, MySQL crea un índice `UNIQUE`.

La siguiente declaración ilustra cómo crear una restricción `UNIQUE` cuando creas una tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
...
   UNIQUE KEY(index_column_1,index_column_2,...) 
);
```

En esta declaración, también puedes usar el `UNIQUE INDEX` en lugar de la `UNIQUE KEY` porque son sinónimos.

Si deseas agregar una restricción única a una tabla existente, puede usar la instrucción `ALTER TABLE` de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE KEY(column_1,column_2,...);
```

### Código para tu contexto

Podrías crear el índice de este modo:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_registro
ON registro(Fecha, Nombre, Tipo, Asiento);
```

Ese índice impedirá que para la misma `Fecha` el mismo `Nombre` tenga más de una fila con el mismo `Tipo` y `Asiento`.

También lo puedes crear en forma de restricción, mediante `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE registro
ADD CONSTRAINT uk_registro UNIQUE KEY(Fecha, Nombre, Tipo, Asiento);
```

A la hora de crear nuevas tablas, puedes definir los índices únicos con la sintaxis mostrada más arriba.

### ⚠ IMPORTANTE ⚠

Cabe destacar que, antes de crear un índice o restricción las condiciones del mismo deben darse en la tabla. Si no se dan debes hacer una revisión manual de la misma (o crear un programa de normalización si son muchos registros) para adaptarla a dicha restricción. O sea, si en la tabla hay filas duplicadas con respecto al índice que vas a crear, la sentencia de creación fallará.

### El índice `UNIQUE` y `NULL` en MySQL

A diferencia de otros sistemas de bases de datos, MySQL considera los valores `NULL` como valores distintos. Por lo tanto, puedes tener múltiples valores `NULL` en el índice `UNIQUE`.

Así es como se diseñó MySQL. No es un error a pesar de que se informó como un error.

Otro punto importante es que la restricción `UNIQUE` no se aplica a los valores `NULL`, excepto para el motor de almacenamiento `BDB`.

---

### Enlaces

- [Using MySQL UNIQUE Index To Prevent Duplicates (en inglés)](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/)
- [Manual de Referencia de MySQL (en inglés)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)